# "Talkative" badge on meta

Tags: support, bug, chat, badges

Yesterday I was awarded the `Talkative` badge on the main site for one message being starred out of ten message posted in chat.

According to me, chat is same for main as well as meta site. So, why I didn't receive the badge here, on meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, badges are separate for the main and meta sites. Some badges just can't be obtained on meta (even though they [appear in the list of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121922/295232)), and the chat badges (Talkative and Outspoken) are part of those.

The chat server is shared with all other Stack Exchange sites (except Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange which have their own server). You got a talkative badge on Physics Stack Exchange, but not on Mathematics Stack Exchange, even though it uses the same chat server. Why? Because the 10 messages were posted in chatrooms 'parented' to Physics Stack Exchange. It's not possible (except for some [hacking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325101/295232) or [old cases/bug leftovers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13775/backup-room--the-h-bar)) to have a chatroom parented to Physics *Meta* Stack Exchange, therefore you can't earn the badge here.

Comment: We do actually have [a chat room whose parent is Physics Meta SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13775/backup-room--the-h-bar). It's rarely used, but it is open for anyone to post in, so if you post some messages there and someone else was motivated to star one of them, maybe you _could_ get the badge on this site.

Comment: @DavidZ [this user](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8563/emilio-pisanty?tab=badges) doesn't have the badge and [plenty of messages, including starred ones](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=i&user=38598&room=13775) in that room. Presumably the script for these badges has been disabled on meta altogether.

Comment: Ah maybe so. I don't know any more than you do about why the badge wouldn't be awarded, but I wanted to point out that it is possible to have a chat room whose parent is the meta site.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out!